# Saving QR code into folder using Endroids code generator

Tags: php

I am using the example code from the [endroid repository](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode) (`QrCode.php`)

```
public function render($filename = 'Images', $format = 'png')
{
    $this->create();

    if ($format == 'jpg') {
        $format = 'jpeg';
    }
    if (!in_array($format, $this->image_types_available)) {
        $format = $this->image_type;
    }
    if (!function_exists('image'.$format)) {
        throw new ImageFunctionUnknownException('QRCode: function image'.$format.' does not exists.');
    }

    if ($filename === null) {
        $success = call_user_func('image'.$format, $this->image);
    } else {
        $success = call_user_func_array('image'.$format, array($this->image, $filename));
    }
    if ($success === false) {
        throw new ImageFunctionFailedException('QRCode: function image'.$format.' failed.');
    }

    return $this;
```

I am trying to get the QR code to be saved into a folder called images
it's in the same folder as the QR code generating file (`QRCode.php`).

So far it's not working, I don't see any images created in the folder, and I am not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Can you post code and error message if available.

Comment: Please show us your code and current output.

Comment: There is no error message ,it just doesn't do anything..

Comment: Please post your code snippet

Comment: @Overdrivr All of the code I am currently using is on the github page.The only thing I've currently added is so that it generates a random name for the qr code..

Comment: That's especially the thing you have added that is interesting. I will edit your post to show you how to properly insert code, images are not the correct way

Comment: @Overdrivr thanks for editing it that way, I didn't know how to do that myself so I put an image instead